# How can I select just one column from a data frame in R that meets certain condition

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am doing some exercises but I do not get the expected output.
I created a data frame with 4 columns. a b,c,d
I want to see in my output column c when column d only has values ( B and C) only.

The way I am doing is
subset(DFAsg1, b == "B" | y == "C")

this returns all the columns in the data frame, but I want to select only column c.

Comment: you mentioned columns as 'c', 'd', but in the code it is 'b', 'y'?  Based on the condition showed, maybe you want `if(all(DFAsg1$d %in% c("B", "C"), na.rm = TRUE)) DFAsg1['c']`

Answer (score 1):

```
subset(DFAsg1, b == "B" | y == "C", select = "c")
```